# Constructing a base 64 string upto a given length and of same size

Tags: c#, string, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was reading through this tutorial https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/ for implementing a azure method described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block.

In order to implement this method we require an block id which is:

1. A valid Base64 string value that identifies the block.
2. Prior to encoding, the string must be less than or equal to 64 bytes in size.
3. For a given blob, the length of the value specified for the blockid parameter must be the same size for each block.

Note that the Base64 string must be URL-encoded.

So inorder to achieve that author says:

> "I usually just number them from 1 to whatever, using a block ID that
>   is formatted to a 7-character string. So for 1, I’ll get “0000001”.
>   Note that block id’s have to be a base 64 string."

and uses this code:

```
string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))));
```

Now, this is Base64 no doubt but how she is fulfilling condition 2 and
 3. Because formatting to "0000000" means 23 convert to "0000023" but more then 7 digit number will remain same ex "999888777" which
 violates 3 condition and also by considering 7 digits, how she is able
 to achieve a 64 byte string to fulfill condition 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at #3, the block ids must be of same length. Thus if you use:

```
string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))));
```

What you're essentially saying is that the maximum block id (or block number in your case) would be `9999999`. If you think that you would need to use of block id more than 7 characters (say 9 characters starting from 100000000), then you would use code like the following:

```
string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("000000000"))));
```

Then all the block ids will be of same length.

Whatever sequence you choose, you just have to ensure that when you convert any number in that sequence to a string all of them must be of same length.

A few other things I would like to mention are:

- There can be a maximum of 50000 blocks for a blob. You can't split a file in more than 50,000 chunks (blocks) to upload them as blocks.
- When the blocks are uploaded, you can upload them in any order i.e. you can first upload block #999 and then upload block #0. What matters is the payload for commit block list. The final blob that gets constructed and saved in blob storage is on the basis of block ids order specified in the commit block list.

What works for me is the following code (assuming the block id numbers are sequential numeric starting from 0):

```
string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("d6"))));
```

Comment: Yeah I did see your code also using javascript, you also did like this i.e. considering 7 digits. But, gaurav how are we fulfilling the condition that string must not be more than 64 byte long.

Comment: `But, gaurav how are we fulfilling the condition that string must not be more than 64 byte long` - This 64 bytes restriction is before it gets converted to base64 encoded string i.e. the base string. So you can't have `string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("d64"))));` as it will have a string bigger than 64 bytes.

Comment: And when I am converting this code into Java i.e. 
String formattedID= "BlockId"+String.format("%07d",blockNumber);
String blockId=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(formattedID.getBytes("utf-8"));
when I am entering number more then 7 digit its actually allowing that number. I know 50000 limit but how to avoid this so that my users don't do any mistake accidentally.

Comment: This is something you handle in your code and don't allow your users to pick this number. So we know that the limit is 50000 blocks. Assuming you're allowing each block size to be 1MB, then maximum you can upload is a size 50000MB. Assuming your user is uploading a 100000MB blob. In this case, you would set the block size to be 2MB to stay in 50000 limit.

Comment: Thanks. Although, I am not still sure with blockNumber.ToString("d6") i.e. how it is restricting string to 64 bytes but I will search around. Thanks mate and this limits is actually very less w.r.t to Amazon.